# How to improve the electromagnetic field in this HFSS design for microstrip patch antenna?

Tags: antenna, patch-antenna

[electromagnetic field for my patch antenna design][image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JsW0.png)]

The thing is I am trying to design a patch that resonates at four different frequencies with the dimensions of 13mm x 13mm x 0.25mm. I am actually new to this. So, I want to know what does the electromagnetic field areas that doesn't have any arrow marks represent. How does that impact my patch and how to improve it?

[S11 parameter for my patch antenna][image]

I was designing a patch to resonate at 403 MHz, 915 MHz, 1400 MHz and 2450 MHz but, this is what I got so far. So it will be helpful to know how to improve my patch.

Comment: you're not visualizing the "electromagnetic field", your visualizing the E-field alone. And there's arrows everywhere on your plane, it seems – just that they are small compared to the very large ones on the right hand side of your picture.

Comment: But honestly, this feels like you're not really used to the tooling, and maybe not even used to a field-based understanding of antennas, yet. So, don't start with a quad-band arbitrary shape antenna like yours – that's incredibly complicated. Start with a single dipole, or a square patch over a ground plane. If that works, start tuning the shape of the patch to make it work at a specific frequency. When you can do that, you can start manipulating shapes in your overly complicated quad-band antenna. You're trying to tailor a suit, but you've yet to learn how to sew simple things.

Comment: and the bad news here is: if your simulation is actually correctly simulating the antenna, then it is pretty much useless at all four of your frequencies. Not that you're simulating it over a meaningful range – fix simulation to actually only cover maybe 300 MHz to 3000 MHz. You don't care about what happens at 100 MHz or at 8 GHz, at all.

Comment: Well thanks for your comments. I will keep that in mind. Thank you

Comment: Please don't just keep it in mind, start acting on it; I've given concrete recommendations on what to do.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I will practice as you recommended.